# WPF MDI maximize box

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, mdi, mdichild

I'm using the WPF Multiple Document Interface from this site http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/. How can I maximize the box inside the code the same way it is done when I click maximize button?

```
<DockPanel>
  <mdi:MdiContainer Theme="Luna" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0 20 0 0" Name="MainMdiContainer">
  <mdi:MdiChild Name="TestWindow"  Title="Child Window" Background="AliceBlue" Resizable="True" />
  </mdi:MdiContainer>
</DockPanel>
```

I've tried something like

```
TestWindow.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
```

but when I do so I cannot see the buttons I normally see when I press the Maximize button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works. Your problem must be somewhere else.

[image: Before resize]

[image: After resize]

**XAML :**

```
    <mdi:MdiContainer Grid.Column="2"  x:Name="Container" Background="#bdbdbd" AllowDrop="True">
        <mdi:MdiChild Name="TestWindow" Title="Child Window" Background="AliceBlue" Resizable="True" />
    </mdi:MdiContainer>
```

**C# :**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TestWindow.MouseDown += TestResize;
    }

    private void TestResize(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var mdiChild = sender as MdiChild;
        if (mdiChild != null)
        {
            mdiChild.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        }
    }
}
```

**Note :** 
I use a modified version of WPF MDI because there is a bug in the mode maximized for the current version. The content height is bigger than the MdiChild content height. 
I posted on codeplex a solution : 
http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/discussions/543694

Comment: I've tried your solution and it seems to work, however when I try to resize TestWindow with just TestWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized(without event) it still doesn't work.